# How to add multiple detailviewcontrollers in a Master Detail Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I create a project in which MasterDetail is the design template.

The problem is that different detail views have to be displayed with different button clicks of master view. Can I do it with the help of different notifications?

I am very much new to Objective C and native applications.

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: There are probably easier way to do this, but I set-up manual push segues to all of my different detail views. Then I write in buttonDown events script to manually trigger the segue. Also have you considered using the same view and changing the content as needed?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is your `detailViewController` is `UINavigationControlller`. Add `all controllers in UINavigationControlller`.

Now `popToViewController` `depending` upon `MasterDetail's button clicks`.

For **example** `button` in `MasterDetail`

```
if(button.tag == 0)
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:button.tag]];
}
```